# size cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java

I tried a basic enumeration program below in eclipse. while accessing the **size** in class **Enumeration**. I am facing the above mentioned error.....!

```
class Shirt{

    enum ShirtSize{SMALL,MEDIUM,LARGE,XL}
    ShirtSize size;
}
public class Enumeration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Enumeration clothes=new Enumeration();
        clothes.size=Shirt.ShirtSize.LARGE;
        System.out.println("Size: "+clothes.size);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't set the size of an Enumeration

Comment: You should post a **full stacktrace** when describing the error you encountered. Please see the Help Center for how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your `Enumeration` class has no `size` member. Your `Shirt` class does, but not your `Enumeration` class. If you did `Shirt s = new Shirt()` you could so `s.size = Shirt.ShirtSize.LARGE`, but not on `clothes` as it's an `Enumeration`, not a `Shirt`. Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future.

Comment: @Sacha - This is the OP's own `Enumeration` class, not the JDK's.

Comment: What makes you think that you could assign `Shirt.ShirtSize.LARGE` to this just because you created an enum?

Comment: Though Sacha made a good point.  Java already has a class `Enumeration`, the op probably should be using a different class name to avoid confusion. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh yes I see now.. Why is OP creating an Enumeration inside its own class?? lol

Comment: Side note: I'd probably avoid using the class name `Enumeration`, as it's a fairly common [standard interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html). You *can*, but...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ... but you end up with a situation like you have here where people thought that the OP was referring to the standard interface instead of his own class.

Comment: @EJoshuaS - Agreed, hence my "side note" above. :-)

Comment: Change `Enumeration clothes=new Enumeration();` to `Shirt clothes=new Shirt();`, and problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are instantiating the wrong class.

Instead of `Enumeration` you should instantiate `Shirt`, as in:

```
class Shirt{

    enum ShirtSize{SMALL,MEDIUM,LARGE,XL}
    ShirtSize size;
}

public class Enumeration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shirt clothes=new Shirt(); // fixed here!
        clothes.size=Shirt.ShirtSize.LARGE;
        System.out.println("Size: "+clothes.size);
    }
}
```